# Load a Bluetooth driver on top of a generic TTL-232R->USB cable

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, bluetooth, serial-port, uart

I have one of these [TTL-232R->USB](http://www.digikey.de/product-detail/en/TTL-232R-RPI/768-1204-ND/4382044?WT.mc_id=IQ_8824_G_pla4382044&wt.srch=1&wt.medium=cpc&WT.srch=1&mkwid=sWf4Ankti&pcrid=106486892420&pkw=&pmt=&pdv=c) cables which I usually use to access a terminal on an embedded board. They are usually detected like this:

```
[89702.948822] usb 2-3.7: new full-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[89703.053567] usb 2-3.7: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[89703.053570] usb 2-3.7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[89703.053573] usb 2-3.7: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[89703.053575] usb 2-3.7: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[89703.054082] pl2303 2-3.7:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[89703.055093] usb 2-3.7: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB1
```

However, for this specific case I'm physically connecting the cable to the UART pins of a [Bluetooth chip](http://www.cypress.com/file/139841/download).

Here is an example of `dmesg` when a dedicated USB Bluetooth dongle is plugged:

```
[   68.042031] usb 3-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using ohci-platform
[   68.308106] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0a12, idProduct=0001
[   68.308130] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[   68.308141] usb 3-1: Product: CSR8510 A10
[   68.405627] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   68.405833] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   68.405846] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   68.405883] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   68.405903] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   68.405974] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   68.438517] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   68.901221] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   68.901243] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   68.901281] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

The appropriate driver exposes the Bluetooth device as a HCI device.

My goal is to get the TTL-232R connected directly to the UART pins of a Bluetooth chip to be detected as a HCI device. The Bluetooth chip has the required firmware loaded.

From the perspective of how the kernel detectes which drivers are loaded for what device, is this a plausible plan, and how would one approach executing it?